# Is $P_{2n} \ge 2P_n$ and $\pi(2x) \le 2\pi(x)$ inconsistent to the Prime k-tuple conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I posed a conjecture as follows that is a special case of [Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture):

> > For $n, x \ge 2$ be two integers then:
> >      $$P_{2n} \ge 2P_n$$ 
> >     and 
> >     $$\pi(2x) \le 2\pi(x)$$

Where $P_n$ is $n$-$th$ prime and $\pi(x)$ is [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)

**My question:** Is the conjecture above contradictory (inconsistent) to the [Prime k-tuple conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple)? I am looking for a proof, comment or reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\pi(2x)<2\pi(x)$ for any $x\geq 11$. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738347/proving-that-pi2x-2-pix). Similarly, it follows from standard bounds that $P_{2n}>2P_n$ when $n$ is sufficiently large.